# python call child method from parent method

Tags: django

Here's the idea: I have a "base" class called `AdBase` and I want a "generic" method like "`get_infos()`".
From there I can have many child classes: `AdRealEstate(AdBase)`, `AdCar(AdBase)`, `AdTrading(AdBase)`, etc.

From there I have a model: `Clip` that has a link to `AdBase`, like this!

```
class AdBase(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True,
                             blank=False)
    def get_infos(self, max_len=55):
        return [self.title]


class AdRealEstate(AdBase):
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=0, default=0, null=True,
                       blank=False, default_currency='EUR')

    def get_infos(self, max_len=55):
        result = super().tab_infos()
        result.extend([_("Price: {}").format(str(self.price) or ''),])
        return result


class Clip(BaseModel):
    ads = models.ManyToManyField(AdBase, related_name='clips',
                                 through='ClipAd')
```

I just want to do something like:

```
for ad in Clip.object.get(pk=1).ads.all():
    print(ad.get_infos())
```

The problem is that `ad` in the loop can be `AdRealEstate`, `AdCar`, `AdTrading`, etc. so I would like to call the `get_infos()` **of the children**, and it only calls `get_infos()` of `AdBase`.

What is the generic way to make `ad.get_infos()` *based on the class*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least three ways of doing this are:

1. Make `AdBase` an abstract base class (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), and make `get_infos` an abstract method.
2. only implement `get_infos` at the derived classes. `Clip` can still call these methods, as the object it holds is an instance of one of these derived classes.
3. Have a `get_infos` method at the base class call `get_infos_impl`, which is a method that is implemented by all the derived classes.

Comment: I check your answer as valid: I choose the 3rd solution. I thought Python could handle this better.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Django-specific and does not relate to Python class inheritance.

Your model definition states that `Clip.ads` is a reference to the `AdBase` model. As such, you will only get `AdBase` instances from the `ads` related manager.

If you want to have multiple `AdBase` subclasses and have `Clip` refer to any of them, you have two options:

**Traverse the base model to the child**

The way you're subclassing Django models implements "multi-table inheritance" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). This includes a "magic" OneToOne field on the parent model that refers to the subclass.

You would end up doing something like:

```py
for ad in Clip.object.get(pk=1).ads.all():
    try:
       print(ad.adrealestate.get_infos())
    except DoesNotExist:
      # No AdRealEstate for that object
      pass
```

There might be other ways of determining what subclasses are available at `Clip.ad` for a given Clip instance instead of handling the DoesNotExist exception, but I can't recall right now.

**Use a generic relation**

Look into the `GenericForeignKey` field provided by Django's `contenttype` framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). This will show you how to setup a relation to an arbitrary object that does not have to be of a single specific Model.